# Load theme error? How do I fix this so people can see my website?

Tags: functions, theme-development, wp-blog-header.php

When people try to open my blog all they see is

```php
 ?> ?> ?> /** * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme. * * @package WordPress */ /** * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it. * * @var boo
```

Is this an easy fix or have I been hacked?

Comment: have you been modifying `wp-config.php`, files in the top folder of WordPress such as `index.php` or files in the `wp-admin`/`wp-includes` folder recently? It looks like either you/a dev/or malware has modified the files but made mistakes opening and closing PHP tags.